# List of unquoted names to list of strings

Tags: r, symbols, rlang

Consider a simple function for converting unquoted names to a <s>list of strings</s> character vector:

```
fun <- function(...) {
  return(sapply(rlang::ensyms(...), rlang::as_string))
}

> fun(abc, def)
"abc" "def"
```

**Question**: How can I write a similar function that takes a list of unquoted names instead of using ellipsis (`...`)?

```
foo <- function(x) {
  return(???)
}

> foo(list(abc, def))
"abc" "def"
```

Edit: The use of `rlang::ensyms` is relevant, since I want the function to "throw an error when the defused expressions are not simple symbols".

Answer (score 1):

fun in the question converts its arguments to a character vector, not a list of strings. If you want to convert it to a list of strings then use fun2 below.  (See [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2022-August/081947.html) for more info on `...()`.  Can optionally use `match.call()[-1]` in its place.)

Now fun3 uses non-standard evaluation accepting an argument which must be of the form list(abc, def) and ends up calling fun2 to process it. If you did want to use fun from the question replace "fun2" with "fun" in fun3.

No packages are used.

Note that it is questionable whether all this is a good idea.  Using non-standard evaluation generally gets you into trouble when you don't want to hard code names.

```
fun2 <- function(...) {
  L <- lapply(substitute(...()), as.character)
  stopifnot(all(lengths(L) == 1))
  L
}
fun2(abc, def) # test

fun3 <- function(x) {
  s <- substitute(x)
  s[[1]] <- as.name("fun2")
  eval(s)   
}
fun3(list(abc, def)) # test
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed the typo about the character vector being returned.

Comment: Can you explain what `()` in `...()` does? Very interesting use of `s[[1]]` in `fun3`.

Comment: Expanded upon and moved comment to answer.